# Передача значений в Style WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Как передать значения их элемента в стиль, который к нему привязан?

У меня имеется стиль, который полностью переделывает стандартную кнопку. Но возникла проблема как передать в стиль надписи, подписи и ToolTip.

Кнопки у меня изначально лежат в ItemsControl, который привязан к коллекции.
Поэтому и возникла необходимость передавать значения в стиль, чтобы не писать много лишней разметки для каждой кнопки и иметь всегда возможность просто удалить один элемент из List'a в коде, и не лезть в разметку.

Вот код ItemsControl, который привязан к листу типизированному классом Command. В этом классе предполагаю хранить саму команду для кнопки, название команды для пользователя, иконку и описание для ToolTip

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleLeft}">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    </Grid>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Вот подключенный стиль:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleLeft"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,2"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Height="75"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Background="#FF646464">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Из разметки предварительно выкинул все, что не работало. Пытался в стиле переопределить основные настройки. А потом уже добавить контент и команду в разметке ItemsControl'a. Но пока вышло только добавить команду, с ней проблем нет.

Вопросы:

Как работать с картинкой в коде C#, чтобы потом ее передать в `<Image Source="{//сюда//}"/>`?
Как передать описание для ToolTip?

Comment: Подробнее опишите с примерами кода, пока ничего не понятно

Comment: Как обычно: через свойства элемента. Если их не хватает, то через attached property.

Comment: @Андрей c утра зайду с рабочей машины, и добавлю примеры кода.

Comment: @Андрей обновил вопрос.

Comment: @VladD обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример с картинкой.

Для начала, чтобы передать картинку, нам нужно какое-то свойство. Можно использовать `Tag`, но это одноразовое решение, а нам надо много, так что навесим attached property:

```
static class ButtonExtensions
{
    public static ImageSource GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ButtonExtensions));
}
```

Далее, наш стиль. Добавим картинку:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonWithImage">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Height="75"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="#FF646464"
                    TextBlock.Foreground="White">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding (local:ButtonExtensions.Image),
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

(`(local:ButtonExtensions.Image)` — это синтаксис для привязки к attached property, `local` — это namespace.)

Используем в коде:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonWithImage}"
        local:ButtonExtensions.Image="diskette.jpg">
    This is button content
</Button>
```

Получаем:

[image: кастомная картинка]

Всё!

---

Для случая `ItemsControl`, у меня работает так:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonWithImage}"
                    local:ButtonExtensions.Image="{Binding Image}">
                This is button content
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
public class MyVM
{
    public string Image { get; }
    public MyVM(string imagePath) => Image = imagePath;
}
```

```
DataContext = new MyVM[] { new MyVM(@"diskette.jpg"), new MyVM(@"diskette.jpg") };
```

Comment: А если кнопки у меня лежат в ItemsContol? я ведь не могу каждой привязать картинку, нужно напрямую с кода передать ее...

Comment: пока вижу такой вариант:
реализовать свойство в котором будет храниться картинка с помощью

'using (FileStream source = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    ImageSource imageSource = new ImageSource(source);
}'

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Ну то есть как это не можете? Всегда можно было привязать. Вы не пользуетесь MVVM? Кладёте коллекцию VM-значений в `ItemsSource`, и привязываете всё, что нужно.

Comment: просто в вашем примере привязана картинка напрямую...

Comment: можете поделиться как работать с изображением именно в коде, тк вариантом очень много: класс Image(в разных сборках), класс ImageSource, Bitmap и тд. Осталось разобраться как загрузить картинки именно в код, перепробовал несколько вариантов, все равно ошибку бьет

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Ну у меня ж упрощённый пример. А привязывать к ImageSource можно просто строку с адресом, кажется. Сейчас проверю.

Comment: пробую сделать так:

`var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/test.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            image = new Image();
            image.Source = bi;`

Но все равно не отображается, это все у меня в конструкторе прописано.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66705/discussion-between-uporotayapanda-and-vladd).